# Java beans binding in GUI

Tags: java, swing

I created a `User` bean class and bind it to a `JTextField`.  I'd like to update the textfield when a method `setName` of the bean is call.  Here is the code:

```
package newpackage;

import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport;

public class User {

    private String name;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(null, null, null);
    }

    private final PropertyChangeSupport propertyChangeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        propertyChangeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        propertyChangeSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }
}
```

I use NetBeans to design a GUI.  It works.  But I was wondering whether it is a correct way to implement bean binding with a Swing component.

Comment: If this is a new application, consider JavaFX instead of Swing. It also comes with property binding support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost. Try something like this (untested):

```
public void setName(String name) {
       String oldName = this.name;
       this.name = name;
       propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("name", oldName, name);
}
```

See the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/beans/PropertyChangeSupport.html).